# Does anyone know how Khan Academy hides the YouTube video title bar for an embedded video using the YouTube Iframe API?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm developing a project in Angular 15 and I would like to hide the title of the YouTube video using the YouTube player.
I have already read the documentation and know that the "showinfo" parameter is deprecated, but I have seen that Khan Academy can do it.

I use the "showinfo=0" parameter, but it doesn't work for me, and it seems to work for them.

You can see an example in the following link:
[example](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:foundation-algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:algebra-overview-history/v/origins-of-algebra)

I want to hide the title bar of the YouTube video when the cursor hovers over the video and when it is paused, just like Khan Academy does.

In Angular, I have the youtube-video.component.ts component where I insert the Youtube player.

```
 const playerVars = {
  cc_load_policy: 1,
  autoplay: 0,
  enablejsapi: 1,
  iv_load_policy: 3,
  modestbranding: 1,
  autohide: 0,
  controls: 1,
  disablekb: 0,
  rel: 0,
  showinfo: 0,---->This param is deprecated but it works for Khan Academy
  fs: 1,
  playsinline: 1
};
```

////-------

```
public video: any;
public player: any;
public reframed: Boolean = false;
startVideo() {
  this.reframed = false;
  const htmlId = this.playerService.generateUniqueId();
  this.htmlID = htmlId;

  this.player = new window['YT'].Player('youtube-player', {
    videoId: 'wtrrr15mbvQ',
    playerVars: playerVars,
    events: {
      'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this),
      'onError': this.onPlayerError.bind(this),
      'onReady': this.onPlayerReady.bind(this),
    }
  });

const container = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#youtube-player');
this.container_player = container;
this.renderer.setAttribute(container, 'id', htmlId);
this.playerService.loadPlayerApi({
  protocol: this.getProtocol()
});
```

}

///------
playerService

```
loadPlayerApi(options: IPlayerApiScriptOptions) {
   const doc = YouTubeService.win.document;
   let playerApiScript = doc.createElement("script");
   playerApiScript.type = "text/javascript";
   playerApiScript.src = `${options.protocol}://www.youtube.com/iframe_api`;
   doc.body.appendChild(playerApiScript);
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They have a custom stylesheet that hides the relevant parts of the video player. Notice how disabling this particular rule causes the title bar to become visible on hover again.

[image: An embedded YouTube video with no title bar. The browser development console is open showing an applied display:none CSS rule.]

[image: The same embedded YouTube video with a visible title bar. The browser development console shows the CSS rule from before has been deactivated.]

There are many media queries and supporting CSS rules to handle the player at different sizes an on different devices. You can find them all by navigating to the `www-player.css` file in the site's assets (click on the link in the top-right corner of the CSS rule).

Here is the primary rule that affects this visibility change. There is no license mentioned in the CSS file, but be aware that this may be proprietary/licensed code and you may not be allowed to use it in commercial software.

```css
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-gradient-top,
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-back-button,
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-title-channel,
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-title,
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-playlist-menu-button,
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-watch-later-button,
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-share-button,
.ytp-hide-info-bar .ytp-chrome-top .ytp-overflow-button,
.ytp-hide-controls .ytp-gradient-bottom,
.ytp-hide-controls .ytp-chrome-bottom {
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
I had noticed that stylesheet, but it doesn't belong to Khan Academy, it's from the Youtube API. That class exists in the .css file, but the problem is how to enable that class for the element inside the iframe.